# multiple forms in Django createView class

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to create a formView(based on Django build-in **CreateView** class) to allow creating new user records, which are from two different models.

Both models sounds like one is **user model** and another is **user profile mode**l.

I wish one form with one submit button to approach it, but I found only one **form_class** could be assigned in one createView class in Django.

So I wonder is that possible to use **CreateView** to approach it? if not, any solution recommended? Appreciated if any assistance from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I find the solution: use the User model and add profile's field in the same form as below

class userCreateForm:

```
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))
    contact_number = forms.CharField(label=_("Contact"))
    contact_address = forms.CharField(label=_("Address"))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (UsernameField(), "email", "contact_number", "contact_address")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
So you have two models for user and user_profile. One user one profile 
so:

Try this:
#models.py
class User_profile(models.Model):
User= models.Foreignkey('User')
#add more user data

#forms.py
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
model = User_profile
fields = ['User']

#views.py
class SomeView(CreateView):
form_class = UserProfileForm()
```

Comment: Thanks Denyce. I tried, but I found the fields ['User'] became a selection field, not a blank username field to fulfill. My request is create a user and user's profile at the same time, but right now the solution you provide seems create user profile for exist user. Could you please have a further look for me. Many thanks.